# Add second line when a column is full from text length ultraWinGrid

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

Is there a way to automatically add a new line or something when a column in my ultraGrid is full? Sometimes when i load some text into a column in my ultragrid it has a longer value length than the available column field, as a result some text stays hidden. So i want when this happens to show the rest of the text in another line. Is this possible in vb.net for ultrawingrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the CellMultiLine property as in the example below. (supposing you have one band and the column with the long text is the second one)

```
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns(1).CellMultiLine = DefaultableBoolean.True
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands(0).Columns(1).VertScrollBar = True
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.DefaultRowHeight = 100
```

The next two lines are optional, but they serve the purpose to show immediately the column with a different height and with a vertical scrollbar